# Running a script when eth0 disconnects

Tags: raspberry-pi, ethernet

How do I get a script to run as soon as `eth0` disconnects?

Comment: Maybe this question and it's answers also help you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360214/systemd-service-run-when-network-interface-up-down-eth0

Answer (score 0):

You could place a hook script into */etc/network/if-post-down.d* and configure the interface in */etc/network/interfaces* to call it on post-down. (I don't want to copy the manpage for `interfaces` here, but it's described there in detail.)

When the interface disconnects, `udev` should notice that and trigger the script.

Comment: This is a very outdated way to achieve that and isn't likely to work on mordern Linux